# Reminder application does not work when I close my main application

Tags: c#

I have a reminder application. In visual studio it works only till visual studio is open. But i want it works also when i close visual studio or even i shut down computer when start it it shows that message

i have seen such app. if  your computer is off at reminder time when you will start you will get message. can any body help me, some one told me i need to use some windows service.

this application matches time and and date withe timer and a month calender. is there builtin function in c# that i can use.

Comment: Build it into a `setup` and look into the `notify icon`

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to build a Windows Service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6.aspx

Comment: Do yuo want your application to be closable by the user (pheraps an icon in the system tray)?

Comment: Sounds like a Windows Service. Or a console application that you configure to be run at startup. Google is your friend.

Comment: I hope this is not the beggining of an attempt to run a keylogger on your girlfriend's computer.

Comment: actually its a part of managment system. not only alone. it works as write message select date  then time then click ok and it hide at that time a time is used which compare setted date time with crrunt date n time when it matches show the message window.                                                              but work when visual studio is running when i close. then not working. how i can do this

Comment: i am bigner i dont know too much. there is no icon displayed in icon tray and i dont know how to do this

Answer (score 4):

> App:

Build your program. Compile your program into an *exe*.

> Close any windows associated:

Have separate Windows Forms, then on the close event, just unload the form. **Not the app**.

> I need the app to start up again when i shutdown and restart.

After compilation, put the *exe* into the startup directory.

*Voila.*

Comment: Epic. Have an upvote, good sir.

Comment: Terribly formatted though.. help me out! `:)`

Comment: There. Feel free to undo it if it's not to your liking ;)